# Multi-Step Registration Profile2

Tags: users

Drupal 7
Modules:   Profile2 Registration Path, Multi-Step Registration, Profile2, Logintoboggan.

I have a Drupal 7 site that has three roles.  User, Advertiser, Auctioneer, each with their own Profile2 fields.  Currently when a user clicks register ALL the profile2 types show up on the page.  The functionality I'm after is, depending on which role they select after filling out username, password and role, the appropriate profile2 type is shown to the user to finish before finishing the user account creation OR something similar.  Is this possible?

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

The [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module allows you to create different registration forms to register users using different roles and different profile types.

Comment: I forgot to include that module in my list.  I'm using that.  And works by going to <profile-type>/registration, which is perfect.  But I have a login block that defaults to /user/registration (which will not work in my use case)  What is the most elegant way to show the profile types I have created as the main part of the registration flow.   I want to the user to be able to either select a role or a profile from the start.  Is this possible?